# Query on OpenCL 2.0 support

Tags: opencl

Does the Blender-2.76 support any of the OpenCL 2.0 features like SVM, C11, atomics, etc … ?

I would like to know whether you plan to support the 2.0 in upcoming releases?

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about blenders source code. Try asking developers on [irc or mailing lists](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Contact)

Comment: @sambler  This site is "for people who use Blender...", I don't see how *Blender's* source code is off topic.  Has this been to meta?

Comment: The question is too vague. [http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/OpenCL) for more info.

Comment: @PGmath while python scripting is acceptable the c/c++ source code isn't - [see #4 here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/935) A user need only be concerned with the [list of requirements](http://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) While a developer could give some feedback, the specifics of what parts or features of opencl are used or may be used is only of concern to blender developers.